# Optimize custom probability distribution in Python

Tags: optimization, python, statistics, probability

Consider random variables $X$ and $Y$, their distributions are given. $Z = f_a(X, Y)$ where $f(\cdot, \cdot)$ is a deterministic, not random function $f_a: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ depending on a deterministic real parameter $a$. For example, let  $f_a(X,Y)=\sin X + e^{aXY}$.

I've read a lot about Bayesian modelling and fitting with the help of `pymc3` Python module. But how can I model $Z$ in a frequentist's manner? There's no prior data, no observations, just random variables. I am to  optimize $a$ over setting $\mathbb{E}Z$ to $0$ etc.

What is the most convinient way to do this? I haven't found solution neither in `scipy.optimize` nor `scipy.stats`.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! If you're asking specifically about modelling, especially frequentist vs. Bayesina, http://stats.stackexchange.com might be a better place. If it's about optimization, you should be more explicit about what you're trying to optimize (it's better to give the functions and objectives you're actually interested in, to avoid answers which don't end up helping you). If I understand correctly, this is not a Bayesian problem, but a stochastic programming. I don't think you'll find ready-made functions in `scipy` (or anywhere else), though; you'll need to implement your own.

Comment: @ChristianClason I'm interested in general approach. What's interesting, Excel atRisk  program provides such an optimization

Comment: The more general the approach, the more work you have to put in to apply it to your problem. Also, there's a huge difference between optimization and "setting $\mathbb{E}Z$ to 0". Finally, if I read things correctly, @Risk uses genetic algorithms -- which basically boils down to "guess values for $a$ until you get it right". There's almost always smarter approaches that use problem information (for example, derivatives of the objective function), hence it's important to specify as much information as you can.

Comment: What do you mean "no observations, just random variables"?  What, if anything do you know about the random variables?  Do you have observations of the random variables X and Y, or of Z? If you know nothing and have no observations or data, there's nothing to do, so presumably you have something, but from your question I have no idea what that something is. Can you generate observations of Z given a particular value of the parameter $a$?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone "their distributions are given"  - imagine you have e.g. pdf for $X$ and $Y$

Comment: For any value of $a$, you can compute $EZ$, by two dimensional numerical integration if necessary. So use a numerical equation solver, and use numerical integration to evaluate $EZ$ when called to do so by the equation solver. There should be suitable functions to do this available in Python. It is important to note that you need to know the joint distribution (density) of $X$ and $Y$ if they are not independent.

Comment: Just to be clear, I was referring to using the numerical equation solver to solve the equation $EZ = 0$, presuming that is what you really want to do.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I see. Is there a more efficient way to create a custom distribution depending on $a$ in `scipy.stats`, use its `mean` method to compute expectation and apply `scipy.optimize` to solve the equation?This hand-made approach seems to be rather slow

Comment: I haven't looked into it much, but maybe something like scipy.optimize.fsolve combined with using dblquad from scipy.integrate to do the evaluation required in the func function you have to provide to scipy.optimize.fsolve .

Comment: *"I am to optimize $a$ over setting Z to 0 etc."* What does this mean? $\mathbb{E}Z$ is a *function of $a$*, so $\mathbb{E}Z=0$ is an *equation in one unknown*, not an optimization problem. Also, your question doesn't seem to involve any kind of statistical inference, so "Bayesian" and "frequentist" are probably red herrings here. You seem to have an equation in one variable, where the lhs is given by a double integral—this is not an inference problem.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, the probability density function ($\operatorname{PDF}$) for $Z$ is given by the integral:
$$\operatorname{PDF}(Z) = \int \delta\left(Z - f_a(X,Y)\right) \operatorname{PDF}(X,Y)\operatorname{d}X \operatorname{d}Y.$$ If the transformation $$\left[\begin{array}{c} X \\ Y \end{array}\right] \rightarrow \left[\begin{array}{c} f_a(X,Y) \\ g_a(X,Y) \end{array}\right] $$ is one to one (if not, break it down into regions where it is, and sum) then:
$$\operatorname{PDF}(Z) = \int \frac{\operatorname{PDF}(X(f_a, g_a),Y(f_a, g_a))}{\left|\frac{\partial f_a}{\partial X} \frac{\partial g_a}{\partial Y} - \frac{\partial f_a}{\partial Y} \frac{\partial g_a}{\partial X} \right|}\operatorname{d}g_a. $$ Some of the simpler choices for $g_a$ include $g_a= X$ or $g_a = Y$.

As for how I would do this, given the vague setup, I would set up a [Metropolis-Hastings algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm) to produce a chain of $(Z, g_a)$ pairs from the bivariate density $$\frac{\operatorname{PDF}(X(f_a, g_a),Y(f_a, g_a))}{\left|\frac{\partial f_a}{\partial X} \frac{\partial g_a}{\partial Y} - \frac{\partial f_a}{\partial Y} \frac{\partial g_a}{\partial X} \right|},$$ and just drop the auxiliary variable, $g_a$, when returning results. You may need to implement a "sample every $N^{\mathrm{th}}$ step" limitation to reduce sample correlations. If the numbers don't have to be generated on command, but can be generated as a batch, then you can use the [emcee MCMC sampling package](http://dan.iel.fm/emcee/current/).

Comment: Am I right you supply to calculate $\mathbb{E}Z$ numerically with the help of samle's mean? And how should I compute such $a$ that makes $\mathbb{E}Z$ equal to $0$?

Comment: For that you'll want to turn to the definition of $\mathbb{E} Z$. $$\mathbb{E} Z = \int f_a(X, Y) \operatorname{PDF}(X,Y) \operatorname{d} X \operatorname{d} Y$$
Optimizing for $\mathbb{E} Z = 0$ is the same as minimizing $(\mathbb{E} Z)^2$.

With any optimization problem like this, you probably want to have a deterministic evaluation of the integral (eg scipy.integrate's dblquad), unless you want to custom build an algorithm that allows for minimization of a non-deterministic function.

Comment: but what if I'd like to set, e.g., a 5% quantile of $Z$ to $0$? This problem involves inversed cdf. What's an appropriate algorithm for this case?